# Category page Toobar Block not get rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

i am trying to override block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` but its not work for me.

bellow is my **config.xml** code

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mymodule_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
</config>
```

and my **Toolbar.php** file path is `app/local/Mymodule/Catalog/Block/Product/List`

and code is bellow

```
class Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        echo "111";die;
        parent::setCollection($collection);
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            if($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'qty_ordered') {
                $this->getCollection()->getSelect()
                     ->joinLeft(
                            array('sfoi' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_item')),
                             'e.entity_id = sfoi.product_id',
                             array('qty_ordered' => 'SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered)')
                         )
                     ->group('e.entity_id')
                     ->order('qty_ordered ' . $this->getCurrentDirection());
            } else {
                $this->getCollection()
                     ->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())->getSelect();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But my function not call when i am on category listing page.

So please let me know where i did mistacks

Comment: function is called butmay  issue at parent::setCollection($collection);  it may  be  Mage_Core_Block_Template::setCollection($collection);

Comment: Hi @AmitBera i have try to do die in first line of function but still its not work for me

Comment: @AmitBera check my updated function code. Still function is not calling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to change module group name because it will conflict with catalog module

config.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mymodule_Mycatalog>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mymodule_Mycatalog>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <mycatalog>
        <class>Mymodule_Mycatalog_Helper</class>
      </mycatalog>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <mycatalog>
        <class>Mymodule_Mycatalog_Block</class>
      </mycatalog>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Mymodule_Mycatalog_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Block file `app/code/local/Mymodule/Mycatalog/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php` code:

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Mycatalog_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
}
```

Other possibility:

May be some other module will rewrite your block.If you have used any extension, Go to toolbar.phtml file of your theme then debug code add `get_class($this)` you will get class name there.

Comment: Hi @Prashant Valanda i have change module name but still same problem. I have not created helpers so because of it my block not work?

Comment: Have you created Mymodule_Mycatalog.xml file in etc/moduels?

Comment: Yes I have Mymodule_Mycatalog.xml file and  i have also rewrite model and it works fine for me i just have problem with block only

Comment: May be some other module will rewrite your block.Have you used any extension? Go to toolbar.phtml file debug code add `get_class($this)` you will get class name there and let me know

Comment: Yes i found that its use by "MageWorx_SeoFriendlyLN_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar"

Comment: You need to rewrite this one.